# How can we pass element ID as a variable in an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to write a template that will create a blog feed, like blogging websites with multiple instances of the same kind.
Now, each instance (each blog post) needs its own like button. For implementing this feature, I am using AJAX.
I am able to make changes in the database by clicking the 'follow' button but not able to make changes in the template with the success function.
Here is the template,

```
    {% for question, count, is_follow in zipp %}

<div class="border rounded my-2 px-3 py-1" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #2b6dad;">

<p class="fst-normal">
  <small>Tags: </small>
  {% for tag in question.tags.all %}
    <small><a href="{% url 'tag' tag.slug %}" style="text-decoration:none; color:black"><i>{{tag.name}} |</i></a></small>
  {% endfor %}
</p>

<p><a href="{{question.get_absolute_url}}" style="text-decoration: none; color: black"><h5>{{ question.question }}</h5>
<small>Arguments added: {{ count }}</small></a></p>
<div class="blank" id="{{question.question_id}}">
  {% include 'snippets/follow_question.html' %}
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" style="padding-right: 3px;"></i>Share</button>
</div>

{% endfor%}
```

Script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(event){
  $(document).on('click', '#follow', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var pk = $(this).attr('value');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{% url 'follow_question' %}',
      data: {'id': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function(response){
        var id = $(this).closest('.blank').data('id');
        $(id).html(response['form']);
      },
      error: function(rs, e){
        console.log(rs.responseText);
      },
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

As far as I understand, the problem is in the success function. I am trying to make the changes in the correct instance. I get the idea for it from this question
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7139532/16153497)

follow_question.html

```
<div class='d-flex flex-row'>
<form action = "{% url 'follow_question' %}" method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
  {% if is_follow %}
    <button class = "btn btn-sm btn-success" id='follow' type="submit" name="question_id" value={{ question.question_id }}>Followed</button>
  {% else %}
    <button class = "btn btn-sm btn-success" id='follow' type="submit" name="question_id" value={{ question.question_id }}>Follow</button>
  {% endif %}
</form>
```

Views.py

```
def follow_question(request):
question = get_object_or_404(Question, question_id = request.POST.get("id"))

is_follow = False

if question.follow.filter(username = request.user).exists():
    question.follow.remove(request.user)
    is_follow = False
else:
    question.follow.add(request.user)
    is_follow = True

context = {}
context["question"] = question
context["is_follow"] = is_follow

if request.is_ajax():
    html = render_to_string('snippets/follow_question.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse({'form':html})
```

Comment: `is_follow` is a boolean field ?

Comment: Yes, is_follow is a boolean field.

Answer (score 0):

You can define $(this) as a variable and use it elsewhere, Especially in ajax events functions:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    
    $(document).ready(function(event){
      $(document).on('click', '#follow', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var this_element = $(this) // HERE
        var pk = $(this_element).attr('value'); // HERE
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '{% url 'follow_question' %}',
          data: {'id': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
          datatype: 'json',
          success: function(response){
            var id = $(this_element).closest('.blank').data('id');
            $(id).html(response['form']); // HERE
          },
          error: function(rs, e){
            console.log(rs.responseText);
          },
        });
      });
    });
    
    </script>
```

Comment: I made the changes but it still not working. I am able to change the status in the database but not able to change the button from 'follow' to 'followed' in the template.

Answer (score 0):

If your `is_follow` is a boolean field you have to do like this

```
{% if is_follow %}
    <button class = "btn btn-sm btn-success" id='follow' type="submit" name="question_id" value={{ question.question_id }}>Followed</button>
  {% else %}
    <button class = "btn btn-sm btn-success" id='follow' type="submit" name="question_id" value={{ question.question_id }}>Follow</button>
  {% endif %}
```

you don't have to add this in a form tag if you do this with a **GET** request do as you like I'm giving example with **GET** request you can change it with **POST**

inside your **Ajax** do like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // you don't need to pass a event on document ready
  $(document).on('click', '#follow', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var pk = $(this).attr('value');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '{% url 'follow_question' %}',
      data: {'id': pk},
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function(response){
        // here you have to do nothing or you can just pass a success msg button is automatically changed by Django template
      },
      error: function(rs, e){
        console.log(rs.responseText);
      },
    });
  });
});
```

and inside you view you can do like this

```
def my_ajax_call(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.is_ajax():
       id = request.GET.get('id')
       Mymodel.objects.filter(id=id).update(is_follow=True) 
       # or you can check the value of is_follow by sending it from ajax call 
       to your view and can add toggle condition like this
```

---

```
def my_ajax_call(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.is_ajax():
       follow_status = request.GET.get('is_follow')
       id = request.GET.get('id')
       if follow_status:
         follow_status = False
       else:
         follow_status = True
       Mymodel.objects.filter(id=id).update(is_follow=follow_status)
```

Comment: I have removed the form tag as it is redundant. But the main issue is still there. I am able to change the status in the database. What I am not able to do is to change the button from 'follow' to 'followed' in the template. I have also included the view in the question. Please take a look.

Comment: Try to set `is_follow = ''` instead of `is_follow = False` before if and else.